# Best way to identify messages routed to only one queue (vs 0 queue with alternate exchange)

Tags: rabbitmq

We have setup a RabbitMQ system at my current client using a structure of topic exchanges and binded queues, 
and an alternate exchange (and bound queue) defined to identify any message not routed.

They would now like to add a queue bound (#) to all of the exchanges, so that they can log all traffic into a BAM (Business Activity Monitoring) system.

This is all well, but would mean that from that point any message received would be always routed.

I'd like to know if there is a configuration I can put in place to identify any message that is not routed apart from that BAM queue.

One possibility would be to avoid the # binding and "duplicate" all existing bindings on each exchange to the BAM queue, but that approach is quite heavy configuration wise and means a fair deal of maintenance.

I'm looking for any structure (federation ), exchange to exchange, ... that would allow for an easy identification of messages not routed to any but BAM queue, preferably with a reasonably simple configuration.

**RabbitMQ version: 3.6.5** *(upgrade can be considered)*

Comment: After some reflection, I could possibly see this to work by defining an "entry" exchange bound to 2 queues: bamq and toprocessq, and a shovel in place to take the messages from toprocessq and push them to the exchange to which the processing queues are bound - which has the alternate exchange configuration.
Not my favorite approach as it adds a step in the original flow.

Comment: Have you considered the [firehose tracer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) ?

Comment: Hadn't thought about it, so thanks for the idea. From what I can see it would indeed cover the need, except for the non persistent state, while there is a [feature request](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1002) to enable persistence for it. Would only leave the fact that it's off by default at server startup as a possible issue. Will continue to look for options.